# Is there an error in this program? Calculating PI simulating the throwing of darts JAVA

Tags: java, random, methods, static

I'm supposed to write a program that calculate PI by simulating the throwing of darts on an inscribed circle in a square. It will generate random numbers for the x and y values (coordinate points), if x^2+y^ is less than or equal to one then the dart indeed hit the circle, else it didn't (miss).
It then  calculates pi using this formula: pi = 4 * (hit / total throws). 
This is something similar to Buffon's Needle Experimentation. 
As you can see below, I have written the code, however when I compile it, the values of pi aren't even close to 3.14 :(

```
 /**
 * This program is intended to calculate the value of pi by simulating throwing darts at a dart                  *board.
 * 
 * @author Nataly Carbonell
 * @version 12/13/2014
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Darts
{
public static double[] calcPi(int d, int t)
{


     int hit = 0;
     int miss = 0;
     double [] posX = new double[d];
     double [] posY = new double[d];
     double[] pi = new double[t];
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < d; index++)
        {   
            posX[index] = 2 * Math.random() + - 1;
            posY[index] = 2 * Math.random() + - 1;





            if((Math.pow(posX[index], 2) + Math.pow(posY[index], 2)) <= 1)
            {
                hit++;
            }

            else if ((Math.pow(posX[index], 2) + Math.pow(posY[index], 2))> 1)
            {
                miss++;
            }

    }

    pi[i] = (4 * (hit / d));
    }
   return pi;
}

  public static double calcPiAverage(double[] p, double t)
   {
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
      sum += p[i];
    }
    average = sum / t;
    return average;
    }

    public static void printOutput(double [] p, double ave, int t)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Trial [" + i + "]: pi = ");
        System.out.printf("%5.5f%n", p[i]);


    }
    System.out.printf("Estimate of pi = %5.5f", ave);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many darts per trial? ");
   int darts = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("How many trials? ");
   int trials = in.nextInt();

   double [] pi = new double[trials];
   pi = calcPi(darts, trials);

   double piAverage = calcPiAverage(pi, trials);

   printOutput(pi, piAverage, trials);



    }
 }
```

Comment: If it's not producing the intended results, then yes. It sounds like you have an error. Perhaps you should try to debug it.

Comment: I have tried, many times. I just wanted to get someone else to check it, maybe he or she catches something my eyes didn't.

Comment: What exactly are the values of pi that you get?

Comment: Since it asks for user input, it varies. But usually numbers larger than 5.0 and even though the values are doubles, they never always have zeros after the decimals.

Comment: I would try this: `posX[index] = 2 * Math.random() - 1` and `posY[index] = 2 * Math.random() - 1`. There should be no reason for a `+` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is probably your integer division: cast your `hit` and/or `d` to `double` before taking the ratio here: `(4 * (hit / d))`. If I understand your code correctly, you probably also want to reset `hit` outside your `index` loop but inside your `i` loop.

One more thought: this Monte Carlo approach to estimating pi converges *extremely* slowly so anything you can do to speed it up will help. Since you can calculate `miss` from the values of `hit` and `d` you don't need the `else if` clause. And since you don't use `miss` at all, you don't even need to calculate it. (You can also do better by throwing darts in the positive xy quadrant only but I haven't done this in the code below).

This is your code I've edited:

```
 /**
 * This program is intended to calculate the value of pi by simulating throwing darts at a dart                  *board.
 * 
 * @author Nataly Carbonell
 * @version 12/13/2014
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Darts
{
public static double[] calcPi(int d, int t)
{


     int hit = 0;
     int miss = 0;
     double [] posX = new double[d];
     double [] posY = new double[d];
     double[] pi = new double[t];
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        hit = 0;
        for(int index = 0; index < d; index++)
        {   
            posX[index] = 2 * Math.random() + - 1;
            posY[index] = 2 * Math.random() + - 1;

            if((Math.pow(posX[index], 2) + Math.pow(posY[index], 2)) <= 1)
            {
                hit++;
            }

    }

    pi[i] = (4 * ((double)hit / d));
    }
   return pi;
}

  public static double calcPiAverage(double[] p, double t)
   {
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
      sum += p[i];
    }
    average = sum / t;
    return average;
    }

    public static void printOutput(double [] p, double ave, int t)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Trial [" + i + "]: pi = ");
        System.out.printf("%5.5f%n", p[i]);


    }
    System.out.printf("Estimate of pi = %5.5f", ave);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("How many darts per trial? ");
   int darts = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("How many trials? ");
   int trials = in.nextInt();

   double [] pi = new double[trials];
   pi = calcPi(darts, trials);

   double piAverage = calcPiAverage(pi, trials);

   printOutput(pi, piAverage, trials);



    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, after casting I now get digits after the decimal place ^_^ but values still not close to pi :( and after reseting hit outside the index but inside the i loop, the values got shorter (less than 1) but still not close to pi :(

Comment: It works for me (did you correct the position of the `hit` counter?) -- try 1000000 Darts and 1 trial: I get 3.14321 (like I said, it doesn't converge very fast...)

Comment: If I try 1000000 and more than one trial I get the first trial 3.14321 but the other trials are bigger numbers...weird.

Comment: Ohh it looks like changing the position of the hit worked! ^_^ YAY Thank!

Comment: I mean that yeah hit had to be reseted after each trial :) thank you :)